# Embed the Apache FTPServer (Mina) in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ftp, embed

I'm trying to run a FTP server in my web application.
I've started here : 
http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html
and put this in my FOM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ftpserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>ftpserver-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ftpserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>ftplet-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.18</version>
</dependency>
```

But when starting my Tomcat I got this error:

```
Mar 11, 2016 2:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 11, 2016 2:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/sagitarii] startup failed due to previous errors
```

...and my application stop.

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mina/filter/executor/OrderedThreadPoolExecutor`
. I can't find OrderedThreadPoolExecutor in MINA-3.0.0-M2  !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the class `org/apache/mina/filter/executor/OrderedThreadPoolExecutor` is not in the 3.0 M2 and I can't find any sample code to replace the one I found:

```
    PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
    UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();

    BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
    user.setName("cache");
    user.setPassword("cache");
    user.setHomeDirectory( PathFinder.getInstance().getPath() + "/cache/" );
    userManager.save(user);

    BaseUser scientist = new BaseUser();
    scientist.setName("storage");
    scientist.setPassword("storage");
    scientist.setHomeDirectory( PathFinder.getInstance().getPath() + "/storage/" );
    userManager.save(scientist);

    ListenerFactory listenerFactory = new ListenerFactory();
    listenerFactory.setPort( serverPort );

    FtpServerFactory factory = new FtpServerFactory(); // <<-- ERROR HERE !!
    factory.setUserManager(userManager);
    factory.addListener("default", listenerFactory.createListener());

    server = factory.createServer();
    server.start();
```

Changed to 2.0.13 and it started to work.